# What is the key type for the ssh_host_key file in SSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-agent

In Ubuntu and Fedora in the `/etc/ssh/` directory exists the following files:

```
ssh_host_key
ssh_host_dsa_key (not available in Fedora)
ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_rsa_key
```

For the same set of these files, exists others with the same names but with the `.pub` extension.

I know that `dsa, ecdsa, ed25519` and `rsa` are keys type

**Questions**

- What is the *key type* for the `ssh_host_key` file in SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh_host_key` is the key for the deprecated OpenSSH protocol version 1. It is always RSA.

> **-h** host_key_file
> Specifies a file from which a host key is read. […] The default is `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_key` for protocol version 1, […]

— [`man 8 sshd`](https://web.archive.org/web/20220923155855/https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd)